# link user parameter "value" into event value in firebase event console

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

I'm generating an event in my mobile app using this method:

```
    var Param = {};
    Param.VALUE = response[1];
    firebase.analytics().logEvent(`Purchase_report`, Param);
```

and I am able to receive the log in StreamView and also Event dashboard. I also can see my parameter("VALUE") by correct sent value from my application in these views. However I don't know how may I link this value to the event value and I always see "0" as event value. Please refer to these images for more clarifications:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. The point is if you set a value parameter, it takes about ONE DAY for an update to be appear in the firebase console.So I finally saw my report after one day.